# ASP MVC Route not matching

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm having a problem with MVC Routes that is freaking me out. I have an area, which has a link to a method outside the area. The thing is that when I hit the link, it reloads the page, without calling the correct method. Do you know any way to know which rule or route the server is matching? I mean, I think it could be a route configuration problem, but I'm not figuring it out which route the server is using to match the link.

This is my structure.

/Areas/Dashboard (Area)

/Controllers/TestController.cs with method "TestMethod(int i)"

Inside one of the Dashboard's page, I have a link with href="/Test/TestMethod/1", so I've put a breakpoint in TestMethod but the breakpoint is never reached.

**Update:**
Even calling the method directly from the browser, I can not reach the method.

Can you help me with this?
Thanks!!

Comment: Do other methods in the same controller work?

Comment: You need to post your code. RouteConfig, ActionResults, View etc.

Comment: @SqlACID I have only one method in that Controller. The thing is that I can not find a way to see which route the system is using.

Comment: Mostly because the link is reloading the page (because of the routes) instead of calling the correct method :/

Comment: From the browser, you should call it like <<HostUrl>>/Dashboard/Test/TestMethod/1. Since, the controller and view are hosted inside area, so you have to provide in the formed URL.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found something really weird. My method was called "Change", so to "try", I changed the name to "Set" and it worked!
If anyone knows why this could be...

```
    public ActionResult Set(int id)
    {
        CookieHelper.UpdatePeec((PEEC)id);

        return Redirect("/");
    }
```

instead of

```
    public ActionResult Change(int id)
    {
        CookieHelper.UpdatePeec((PEEC)id);

        return Redirect("/");
    }
```

Thanks!